# What is this spiky red fruit bearing shrub and can I eat it?

Tags: identification, shrubs, fruits

This shrub's fruit reminds me of a hawthorn, but I do not see long sharp thorns like I would expect, only short spikes - so what is this and more importantly can I eat it like a hawthorn fruit? The plants seem to live without much water aside from a fairly rainy climate. This is in the Seattle area - hardiness zone 7.

This picture gives a good view of the leaves and a flower - this seems late in their season since most shrubs bear ripening fruit and no flowers at this point.
[image: view of flower and leaves]

Some of the plants bear pink flowers like the one above, and some white flowers like this one. This picture gives a good view inside the flower.
[image: inside view of flower]

Ouch! These spikes don't cover all of the branches.
[image: spikes on branch]

These little nubs look to me like they might be growth potentials but I don't know enough about shrubs to say for sure.
[image: possibly a growth potential on the branch]

As you can see, the fruits tend to be solitary, the plant is typically about four feet high.
[image: overall view of plant]

Here's a good view of a fruit and the reverse side of a leaf.
[image: fruit and reverse side of leaf]

The fruit is fleshy and contains many seeds. It is soft but not very juicy.
[image: inside view of fruit]

Comment: I answered my own question after some more searching - if anyone has a more detailed answer such as the exact species or other additional information, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Rosa rugosa. There are several cultivars, with different coloured flowers. They're tough roses, widely used in amenity landscaping.

Comment: The description fits remarkably well, as do pictures I find, and while these are not in their native habitat the conditions are similar - soil with high mineral content but low in clay, probably high drainage. It also makes sense as a hardy plant to have been chosen for its particular location, decorative but low maintenance for a public space. I'll wait a little bit for comments and answers to possibly trickle in but this sure seems right.

Comment: @VoidStar - They're lovely shrub roses, with a delicious scent. I've got two in my (very) small garden - Rosa rugosa 'Roseraie de l'Hay' and Rosa rugosa 'Fru Dagmar Hastrup'.

Answer (score 3):

This is CLEARLY a rose - I can't believe I didn't see that earlier. The [Wikiedia article on their accessory fruits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_hip) has a good picture. And yes - rose hips have culinary purposes.

Comment: But you should check where it grows. If it is in wild, where there were no landfill, it should be ok. If it is on gardens, I would never eat it (and because you have two different flowers type, I assume it is not so "wild").

Comment: Oh I wouldn't eat THESE but I developed a general interest in the plant and whether the species is edible (i.e. if I could cultivate it for its fruit). These are growing in the nastiest parking lot runoff of the Northgate Mall, haha.